# Rails get number of people who picked a radio button input option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using devise, and so in my model I'll have a question, answer choices, and a submit button.

```
QUESTION
ANSWER CHOICE (30)
ANSWER CHOICE (20)
ANSWER CHOICE (n)
ANSWER CHOICE (n)
SUBMIT
```

On submit, I want it to show what answer choice was picked by how many people.

For example, if there were 100 people, and 30 people picked the first one, 20 the second, and so forth..how would I go about implementing this in rails?

A question would have_many answer choices, and I would have the form somehow show the answer choices in the select_for tag but for radio buttons, but how do I do the part where the rails app would show how many people picked what in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use aggregate queries using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

Check [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) out.

Example from the Rails documentation:

```
Person.group(:city).count
# => { 'Rome' => 5, 'Paris' => 3 }
```

Comment: How would the rails app know which user picked what choice then?

Comment: Well, I am assuming you have this relationship in your model. Check how your form submission is implemented (how it is saving the data?). If it is not yet, you have to do it first.